# core data fetching and sorting with nil value

Tags: core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I'm facing a problem using Core Data.

In my core data model, I have `Grove` Entity and `Tree` Entity, with one-to-many relationship between `Grove` and `Tree`, and one to one relationship between `Tree` and `Grove`
(each Tree may be in one grove max).

But some `Tree` may be "wild" and not be part of any `Grove`.

I'm trying to use a fetResultController to display all my trees in a table view.
Each Grove would be a section of the table view, and the "wild" trees must be in a separate section.

My code is like this:

```
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Tree" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    // Edit the sort key as appropriate.
    NSSortDescriptor *sectionSortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"Grove.name" ascending:YES];
    NSSortDescriptor *rowSortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"type" ascending:YES];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = @[sectionSortDescriptor, rowSortDescriptor];
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

    NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:context sectionNameKeyPath:@"Grove.name" cacheName:nil];
```

As you can see I'm fetching all Trees.
The first sort descriptor, used to determine the sections is base on the one-to-one relationship from tree to grove, and looks for the grove name.
The second sort descriptor is used to sort the trees inside a given section, and it sorts them by type.

This code works absolutely fine when the trees have a grove defined.
But the trees with grove=nil are not fetched by this request.
Do you know a way to achieve the wanted behaviour ?
Do I have to create a fake grove for the wild trees ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend to make a special `Grove` instance that represents "none", as you suggest.

Anther solution is to fetch the groves and manipulate your table view datasource methods as follows:

- Return the number of results +1 as the number of sections. E.g. the last section for the wild trees.
- Configure the section header according to the returned grove entity.
- Return theGrove.trees.count as the number of rows in a section, make a special fetch for the other trees for the last section.
- etc..

You get the gist. It s a bit more complicated and a non-standard use the fetched results controller, but I have sen it work quite well before.

Comment: I went for the easy solution of the "NONE" Grove